# Probability - Calculate probability of win on multiple bets

Tags: probability, gambling

There's a game where I can bet on the result of a random generated number that could be $1$ or $2$. In fact, I've got $50\%$ probability that the number will be $1$ and $50\%$ probability that it will be $2$.
But what if I bet $10$ times, and I win if I get $1$ just one time? I mean, I could get $2$ four times but then get $1$ and win. Is it true that, if in that $50\%$ of lose probability there's another bet with $50\%$ probability of win, the final probability is $75\%$?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "final probability"? It is true that you have a 75% chance of winning by the end of two turns.

Comment: This is not clear.  The probability of guessing wrong ten times in a row is $\frac 1{2^{10}}\approx 0.000977$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Shanye2020 That's exactly what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Yes I'm asking that. Sorry for my english, I'm italiano. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The probability to guess wrong 10 out of 10 when every single event has a 50 % prob is 100 ÷ (2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2)= 0.09765625. Not 0,000977
But if you place a bett independently one after the other then the stats are higher. If the first event is lets say black the next event has the same probability to be black 50%. So so for 10 wrong guess is 0.097 % for 9 wrong is 100÷(2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2)=0.1953125 
When you are at the last pickk after you where wrong 9 times you have 50-50 % chance. Sorry for my bad english